# Which of Judge Dredd's enemies had a nickname related to "fists"?

Tags: 2000ad

I am looking for a specific one (I just can't seem to put a name to the face in my head).

He was a Karate/martial arts expert that had several big fights with Dredd that mostly ended up in draws (i.e. both of them in bloody pools but neither dead or locked up). Though eventually Dredd may have locked him up (I'm not sure about that though).

His nickname may have been something to do with fists ('death fist' or something similar).

What would be added bonus (and very helpful) is any progs/story line names where Dredd and this character meet up in major events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an official reference as 2000AD online has not opened their wiki to the public.

But with some judicious googeling I have found the character:

```
Name:       Stan Lee
Alias:      Death Fist
Profession: Assassin
```

http://www.comicvine.com/stan-lee/29-29052/all-images/108-245534/deathfist1/105-1847112/
http://www.comicvine.com/stan-lee/29-29052/all-images/108-245534/stanlee2/105-1852577/
http://www.comicvine.com/stan-lee/29-29052/all-images/108-245534/stanlee1/105-1852576/
http://www.comicvine.com/stan-lee/29-29052/all-images/108-245534/stanlee3/105-1852575/

Stories:

```
The Fists of Stan Lee       (Prog 484)
The Return of Death Fist    (Prog 540/541)
Art of Geomancy             (Prog 762/763/764/765)

Shimura: The Harder They Come  JD Mag: 238/239/240/241/242/243
```

I suppose I will wait for the 2000 AD Wiki to become available for the public: